# when will the parent process get exit status of the child, if child calls exec()

Tags: unix

Can any one please let me know when will the parent process get exit status of the child, if child calls exec()?

Is it at the time when child calls exec or when the child process finishes its execution with exec program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent will get the exit status when it calls `wait` after the child has exited (either by calling `exit` or getting a fatal signal).  `exec` is irrelevant.